# Excel VBA Convert object name to string

Tags: excel, vba

lblFirstName has been declared as a Variable

I need to extract the string "FirstName" from it.

One way to do it (if it were a string) would be Right("lblfirstname",len("lblfirstname")-3)

To do that I would need to convert the variable lblFirstName to a string.

Is there any way to do it by creating a UDF or otherwise?

Comment: "`lblFirstName` has been declared as a variable..." did you not use a `String`?  What's the code that's giving issues?

Comment: it would be better if you posted some code to show what you're talking about as "lblFirstName has been declared as a variable" is a very vague comment.

Comment: Dim lblfirstName as Label. It is a label on a userform. I need to fetch its value from another sheet where there are two columns, first with names and second with values. The first column has the value "firstName and second column has the value "Vijay". To fetch that value using a Vlookup function I need to first extract "FirstName" from the variable lblFirstName.

Comment: Still need more than that, I think.

Comment: What is the *purpose* of finding getting the variable's name? I'm guessing that solving your *actual problem* is going to be very different than answering the question that you asked.

Comment: Purpose: A Userform has a label named lblFirstName which needs to be populated with a value from a sheet which has two columns FieldName and Value. The value that has to be displayed in the label is the value in Column 2 corresponding to the value "FirstName" in Column 1. The value "FirstName" does not appear in a fixed row. It varies. Hence, I am using vlookup to find the value. There are many similar instances. I am looking for a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.